# cannot compare query result in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to compare a query result for available cash with a stock price but it is not working and I do not understand why. I do not understand why it is not working since it seems that they *$cash* and *$value* are valid numbers.  This is the line that is giving me the problem.

```
if($cash < $value)
```

this is the whole file

```
<?php

//configuration
require("../includes/config.php");



//query user's portfolio
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{

    // Insert the stock into their portfolio 
    if(preg_match("/^\d+$/", $_POST["shares"])==false){

        apologize("Please enter full share numbers");

    }else{

    $cash = query("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

    // lookup stock
    $stock = lookup($_POST["symbol"]);

    // calculate total sale value (stock's price * shares)
    $value = $stock["price"] * $_POST["shares"];

    if($cash < $value){
        apologize("you do not have enough money");
    }else{


         //insert stock into database      
       query("INSERT INTO shares 
           (id, symbol, shares)
           VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shares = shares + VALUES(shares)",
           $_SESSION["id"], strtoupper($_POST["symbol"]),$_POST["shares"]
             );  

        // substract the share value from cash
        query("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - ? WHERE id = ?", $value, $_SESSION["id"]);

        redirect("/");
      }

    }
}
else
{


// render portfolio
render("buy_search.php", ["title" => "Buy"] );
}
?>
```

This is the *query* function

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{
    // SQL statement
    $sql = func_get_arg(0);

    // parameters, if any
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    // try to connect to database
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            // connect to database
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // prepare SQL statement
    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }
    // execute SQL statement
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);
    // return result set's rows, if any
    if ($results !== false)
    {
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `query` function defined? I would bet that is not returning an integer, but an array or object.

Comment: Please do var_dump($cash) and var_dump($value); and show us the output.

Comment: dump($cash) gives this 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cash] => 0.00
        )

)
dump($value) gives a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($cash[0]['cash'] < $value)
```

According to your debugging comment, it should be this as you need to access the array index `cash` of the array index `0`. If you do not want this format, you should look into how your query results are returned to not have to use nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

$cash is almost certainly not a number, or even a scalar value.

query probably returns an array of result objects, or arrays.